# ConflictException: Base path already exists for this domain name in Serverless AWS

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I had build the applicatoin using the AWS lambda with NodeJS environement. and For the deployement puposes I am using the Serverless Framework. Now When I am trying to deploy my service to the AWS using the Serverless framework with Nodejs template. It is deployed to the server but it's not mapping the custom domain name to my service. Before that, I mapped it, and after automatically mapping it with my domain name. Now when I tried to redeploy the services it's throwing the error of the custome domain couldn't be mapped. I had attached the error logs below. You can check it out. Can you help me with how can I resolve this issue?

Below is the output of my command `sls deploy -s local`.

```
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
Serverless: Load command interactiveCli
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion
Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion:install
Serverless: Load command config:tabcompletion:uninstall
Serverless: Load command create
Serverless: Load command install
Serverless: Load command package
Serverless: Load command deploy
Serverless: Load command deploy:function
Serverless: Load command deploy:list
Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
Serverless: Load command invoke
Serverless: Load command invoke:local
Serverless: Load command info
Serverless: Load command logs
Serverless: Load command metrics
Serverless: Load command print
Serverless: Load command remove
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command slstats
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:install
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:list
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:search
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command upgrade
Serverless: Load command uninstall
Serverless: Load command offline
Serverless: Load command offline:start
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env.local, .env.local:
Serverless:      - STAGE
Serverless:      - SLA_DROPOFF_AFTER_MINS
Serverless:      - AWS_ACCOUNT_CRED
Serverless:      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_CRED
Serverless:      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_CRED
Serverless:      - AWS_REGION_CRED
Serverless:      - LOGLEVEL
Serverless:      - LYFT_REFRESH_TOKEN
Serverless:      - LYFT_ACCESS_TOKEN
Serverless:      - LYFT_CLIENT_ID
Serverless:      - LYFT_CLIENT_SECRET
Serverless:      - LYFT_WEBHOOK_VERIFICATION_KEY
Serverless:      - SMS_APPLICATION_ID
Serverless:      - SMS_REGISTERED_KEY_WORD
Serverless:      - CLIENT_APP_URL
Serverless:      - SECRET_NAME_FOR_LYFT_REFRESH_TOKEN
Serverless:      - SECRET_NAME_FOR_LYFT_ACCESS_TOKEN
Serverless:      - SLS_DEBUG
Serverless:      - LYFT_ACCESS_TOKEN_ROTATION
Serverless:      - AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING
Serverless:      - AWS_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID
Serverless:      - PHARMACY_LOGO_URL
Serverless: Load command create_domain
Serverless: Load command delete_domain
Serverless: Load command login
Serverless: Load command logout
Serverless: Load command generate-event
Serverless: Load command test
Serverless: Load command dashboard
Serverless: Load command output
Serverless: Load command output:get
Serverless: Load command output:list
Serverless: Load command param
Serverless: Load command param:get
Serverless: Load command param:list
Serverless: Load command studio
Serverless: Deprecation warning: CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" property (which could be one of "string", "boolean", "multiple"). Below listed plugins do not predefine type for introduced options:
             - ServerlessOffline for "apiKey", "corsAllowHeaders", "corsAllowOrigin", "corsDisallowCredentials", "corsExposedHeaders", "disableCookieValidation", "enforceSecureCookies", 
"hideStackTraces", "host", "httpPort", "httpsProtocol", "lambdaPort", "noPrependStageInUrl", "noAuth", "ignoreJWTSignature", "noTimeout", "prefix", "printOutput", "resourceRoutes", "useChildProcesses", "useWorkerThreads", "websocketPort", "webSocketHardTimeout", "webSocketIdleTimeout", "useDocker", "layersDir", "dockerReadOnly", "functionCleanupIdleTimeSeconds", "allowCache", "dockerHost", "dockerHostServicePath", "dockerNetwork"
            Please report this issue in plugin issue tracker.
            Starting with next major release, this will be communicated with a thrown error.
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#CLI_OPTIONS_SCHEMA
Serverless: Skipping variables resolution with old resolver (new resolver reported no more variables to resolve)
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Support for "package.include" and "package.exclude" will be removed with next major release. Please use "package.patterns" instead
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#NEW_PACKAGE_PATTERNS
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Invoke aws:package:finalize
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:moveArtifactsToPackage
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:deploy:deploy
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service rxd-administration.zip file to S3 (127.62 KB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
..........................
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Serverless: Invoke aws:info
Service Information
service: rxd-administration
stage: local
region: us-east-1
stack: rxd-administration-local
resources: 61
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  POST - https://[default url for service]
  GET - https://[default url for service]
functions:
  registerTenant: [function names]
  authenticateUser: [function names]
  authorizeUser: [function names]
  renewTokens: [function names]
  changePassword: [function names]
  requestForgotPassword: [function names]
  confirmForgotPassword: [function names]
  forceResetUserPassword: [function names]
  testAuth: rxd-administration-local-testAuth
layers:
  None
Serverless Domain Manager: Info: Found apiId: jefueg03sa for local-api.carierx.app
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: local-api.carierx.app:  ConflictException: Base path already exists for this domain name
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: local-api.carierx.app:  Error: local-api.carierx.app: Unable to create basepath mapping.


 Error ---------------------------------------------------

  Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for local-api.carierx.app
      at ServerlessCustomDomain.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arsla\Documents\iTitans\Projects\rx-delivery\node_modules\serverless-domain-manager\dist\src\index.js:270:27)
      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at rejected (C:\Users\arsla\Documents\iTitans\Projects\rx-delivery\node_modules\serverless-domain-manager\dist\src\index.js:6:65)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.19.0
     Framework Version:         2.35.0 (local)
     Plugin Version:            4.6.0
     SDK Version:               4.2.2
     Components Version:        3.9.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when your Custom Domain Name has a base path mapped to an API that was created manually (as in not by `serverless deploy` run). Delete the offending API mapping and all should work for you.